# Non-numeric Argument to Binary Operator Error When Trying to Add Multiple Secondary Axes with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have an open question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78077012/five-axes-and-nine-data-series-plotted-in-ggplot2) trying to answer a similar question. While waiting for an answer I have been using Gemini (Google's AI for help) but I'm still having issues. Gemini suggested the following solution:

```
ggplot(Process_Data, aes(x = length)) +
   geom_line(aes(y = OD, color = "OD")) +
   geom_line(aes(y = WT0, color = "WT0")) +
   geom_line(aes(y = WT90, color = "WT90")) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = WT180, color = "WT180")) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = WT270, color = "WT270")) + 
   geom_line(aes(y = Zone0, color = "Zone0")) +
   geom_line(aes(y = Zone1, color = "Zone1")) +
   geom_line(aes(y = rpm, color = "rpm")) +
   geom_line(aes(y = speed, color = "speed")) +
   scale_y_continuous("OD", sec.axis = ~list(
    sec_axis(~ . / 46, name = "WT Values (Adjusted)"), 
    sec_axis(~ . / 1, name = "Zone Values (Adjusted)"), 
    sec_axis(~ . / 5, name = "RPM (Adjusted)"), 
    sec_axis(~ . / 115, name = "Speed (Adjusted)"))) +
   theme(axis.line = element_line(), plot.margin = margin(10, 10, 10, 30))
```

When I run this I get this error:
*Error in r[i1] - r[-length(r):-(length(r) - lag + 1L)] :
non-numeric argument to binary operator*

I have searched and searched for an answer to this with no luck. It seems like many people experience similar errors due to misplaced parenthesis, etc. I have been through the code several times and the best I can tell I'm good. But maybe not?

Here's some data:

```
dput(head(Process_Data))
structure(list(length = c(361.91, 362.05, 362.17, 362.3, 362.43, 
362.55), OD = c(228.06, 227.85, 227.88, 228.28, 228.54, 228.82
), WT0 = c(6.67, 6.49, 6.42, 6.6, 6.71, 6.61), WT90 = c(5.61, 
5.44, 5.45, 5.55, 5.59, 5.58), WT180 = c(5.08, 5.1, 5.16, 5.26, 
5.25, 5.23), WT270 = c(6.36, 6.19, 6.04, 6.17, 6.21, 6.28), Zone0 = c(265.25, 
265.07, 265.42, 265.59, 265.59, 265.25), Zone1 = c(46.81, 41.69, 
50.4, 45.27, 50.06, 45.45), rpm = c(40.24, 40.23, 40.26, 40.26, 
40.26, 40.23), speed = c(1.508, 1.545, 1.537, 1.564, 1.554, 1.583
)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have run `anyNA(Process_Data)`,  `str(Process_Data)`, and `summary(Process_Data)` (as suggest by Gemini...) and my data looks good as far as no missing values, non-numerics, or NAs.

What am I doing wrong here? I haven't been able to find any examples of using lists for `sec.axis` within `scale_y_continuous`, could that be the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Looking at the documentation for `?ggplot2::sec_axis`, nothing indicates that ggplot supports multiple secondary axes. Gemini appears to be making up features that don't exist. It seems to work just fine for one secondary axis: `scale_y_continuous("OD", sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . / 46, name = "WT Values (Adjusted)"))` -- you just cannot give it a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with MrFlick's comment.  You've been misled by Gemini.  There's nothing in the documentation for `sec.axis` that indcates you can supply a list.

I believe your fundamental issue is that your data frame is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) - because you have information in your column names that is required for your plot.  This is easily fixed by pivoting your data into long format.

On that basis, does this (simple) code come close to what you want?

```
Process_Data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-length) %>% 
  ggplot() +
    geom_line(aes(x = length, y = value, colour = name))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! To be fair to Gemini it did suggest `pivot_longer` as an option, but didn't say I had to do it. Does pivoting just transpose the data where columns are now rows? I'm trying to get 5 y axes because the data has differenet ranges and I want to be able to see the fine details of each. OD is around 230, rpm can be 0-100, speed 0-5, the WTs 4-7, and the zones from 0-350 or so. This was done here (but with three axes): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71630756/is-it-possible-to-add-a-third-y-axis-to-ggplot2. I've tried to expand it to 5 but I can't get it to work correctly.

Comment: "Does pivoting just transpose the data where columns are now rows?": No, that would be a transpose.  Pivoting is more sophisticated and is central to the concept of [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html)ness.  See, for example, [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html).  The link you provide uses a *totally* different apprach, so it isn't really relevant to your question, though it is to your objective.  When measurements have completely different scales, they may well deserve individual plots...

Comment: ... have you considered `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`?  I fear this is becoming an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).. :-)

Comment: I want to be able to see if certain variables have a response to other changes. To do that the data needs to be on one plot.

Comment: "... the data needs to be on one plot": Really?  Try `Process_Data %>% pivot_longer(-length) %>% ggplot() + geom_line(aes(x = length, y = value)) + facet_wrap(vars(name), scales = "free_y")` or `...  facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales = "free_y")`.

Comment: The `facet_grid(rows = vars(name), scales = "free_y")` option has some value to what I'm trying to do. Thanks.